# Retrieve javascript string from mysql for subsequent edit

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I have constructed an on-line What's On page supported by a mysql database table including a field to contain an event title.  An admin page permits entries to be added, edited and deleted.  More recently I was asked if web links could be embedded in the title field, and found that editing the field to include a link of the form:

```
Click <a class=hdg onclick="newWindow('http://www.address');"> HERE </a>  to open web link
```

would do the trick and open the URL in a new window via the newWindow function.

Unfortunately any attempt to use the admin page to edit such a mysql record corrupts the admin page display, since the string is returned from the title field as the value of a text box, and the link text is then interpreted by the browser so that only part of the field displays in the box on the screen. The remainder of the string appears outside the box, which is confusing to a non-technical user.

A quick and dirty fix is to use Ctrl-A to select the whole of the text box contents when editing, and then type or paste the whole of the title content into the box, when it commits correctly to the database.  However, if anybody knows of a way to code the javascript so that on the one hand it will function correctly as a web link and on the other hand can be edited via an HTML form, I would be glad to know.  Ultimately I guess I'll re-construct the database to hold the actual URL separately and use php to build the javascript link, but meanwhile ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `htmlentities()` to put the field value into the web page with all the HTML special characters replaced with entities, so they won't be interpreted:

```
echo '<textarea>' . htmlentities($value) . '</textarea>';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Barmar.  htmlentities() solves the formatting of the HTML form field, and I've used html_entity_decode() when writing back to the database record to ensure that the stored string works correctly.  That gives me a breathing space to re-build the database with separate fields for the different bits of the string and re-write the php code to put the bits together on the web page where the string is to be used.